# Protractor - Failed: prop is not defined

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

Help please to find an error. I'm learning Protractor and try to create a simple test with Page Object.

```
//login_pageObject.js

let loginContainer = function() {

this.usernameInput = $("input.login-form-01");
this.passwordInput = $("input#login-form-02");
this.loginBtn = $("input.btn");

this.get = function() {
    browser.get("https://www.cosmedicalsupplies.com/login.html");
};

this.setUsername = function(username) {
    usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
};

this.setPassword = function(password) {
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
};

this.clickOnLoginBtn = function() {
    loginBtn.click();
};
};
module.exports = new loginContainer();
```

And

```
//login.js
let loginPage = require('../page_objects/login_pageObject.js'); 

describe('login_logout autotests', () => {

beforeEach(() => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});

it("should sign in", () => {
    loginPage.get();
    loginPage.setUsername("test1");
    loginPage.setPassword("test2");
    loginPage.clickOnLoginBtn();
    //expect.....
});
});
```

So, when I run this code, I have a "Failed: usernameInput is not defined" error. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to it as `this.usernameInput`.

Comment: This error (`ReferenceError`) happens when you're in strict mode - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

I believe `usernameInput` is assumed to be a global variable rather than a member of `loginContainer` when you assign to it without explicitly referring to the object (`this`), and since it was never declared you cannot assign a value to it.